# helper colllection_select, wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 4..6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In collection_select I need pass following arguments. Total 7, but method accept max 6, how me join?

```
<%= f.collection_select :skill_list, Project.tag_counts_on(:skills).order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}, validate: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this syntax

```
<%= f.select :skill_list, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.tag_counts_on(:skills).order(:name), "id", "name"), {},:multiple=> true,:validate=> true,:class=> 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 4..6)

The problem is the way you are passing the arguments to the `collection_select` is wrong.

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method,
>   text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}

`multiple: true` and `validate :true` should be in place of `options = {}` and the `class: 'form-control'` should go into `html_options = {}`. The below should work

```
<%= f.collection_select :skill_list, Project.tag_counts_on(:skills).order(:name), :id, :name, {multiple: true, validate: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the below snippet to populate your `select` tag with the collection**

```
<%= form.select :project, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, "id", "title"),{class: "project_title", include_blank: "--Please Select--"  } %>
```